# Scala.js - Convert Uint8Array to Array[Byte]

Tags: scala, scala.js

How do I implement the following method in Scala.js?

```
import scala.scalajs.js

def toScalaArray(input: js.typedarray.Uint8Array): Array[Byte] =
  // code in question
```

Comment: Well, what did you try so far?

Comment: map with toByte call seems to be working but might not be optimal

Comment: Update your post with the code you tried and explain that you're looking for another solution then. Also optimal on which criteria?

Comment: @GaëlJ I'd assume that OP doesn't want to use `toArray.map(_.toByte)`, because that would at the very least allocate two arrays, and one of them would be twice as large as what's actually stored in the memory. I clicked around through the API, but found no obvious way to do the same without creating any intermediate data structures. I feel that the question is clear enough even as it is.

Comment: I posted it as answer. By optimal I meant performance. Also I don't quite get why I need toByte calls

Comment: Do you need an `Array`? Or would a sufficiently sequence-like structure (like `Seq`) suffice? Because it may be possible to write a wrapper class that implements `Seq` without copying the array, for instance.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo nice idea, might try later. `Array` seems simpler for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the current answers require iterating over the array in user space.

Scala.js has optimizer supported conversions for typed arrays (in fact, `Array[Byte]` *are* typed arrays in modern configs). You'll likely get better performance by doing this:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray._

def toScalaArray(input: Uint8Array): Array[Byte] = {
  // Create a view as Int8 on the same underlying data.
  new Int8Array(input.buffer, input.byteOffset, input.length).toArray
}
```

The additional `new Int8Array` is necessary to re-interpret the underlying buffer as signed (the `Byte` type is signed). Only then, Scala.js will provide the built in conversion to `Array[Byte]`.

When looking at the generated code, you'll see no user space loop is necessary: The built-in `slice` method is used to copy the TypedArray. This will almost certainly not be beatable in terms of performance by any user-space loop.

```js
$c_Lhelloworld_HelloWorld$.prototype.toScalaArray__sjs_js_typedarray_Uint8Array__AB = (function(input) {
  var array = new Int8Array(input.buffer, $uI(input.byteOffset), $uI(input.length));
  return new $ac_B(array.slice())
});
```

If we compare this with the currently accepted answer (`input.view.map(_.toByte).toArray`) we see quite a difference (comments mine):

```js
$c_Lhelloworld_HelloWorld$.prototype.toScalaArray__sjs_js_typedarray_Uint8Array__AB = (function(input) {
  var this$2 = new $c_sjs_js_IterableOps(input);
  var this$5 = new $c_sc_IterableLike$$anon$1(this$2);
  // We need a function
  var f = new $c_sjsr_AnonFunction1(((x$1$2) => {
    var x$1 = $uS(x$1$2);
    return ((x$1 << 24) >> 24)
  }));
  new $c_sc_IterableView$$anon$1();
  // Here's the view: So indeed no intermediate allocations.
  var this$8 = new $c_sc_IterableViewLike$$anon$6(this$5, f);
  var len = $f_sc_TraversableOnce__size__I(this$8);
  var result = new $ac_B(len);
  // This function actually will traverse.
  $f_sc_TraversableOnce__copyToArray__O__I__V(this$8, result, 0);
  return result
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (manual source array value assignments)
[scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/QH1MdS9SRViwhOdXtViQRg)

Comment: Yes :-/ The byte array view had the wrong parameters. It's fixed.

Comment: I've done some tests and found no performance difference with my other proposed solution. Both are ~1.8 faster than `view` variant though

Answer (score 2):

edited per request: tl;dr

```scala
input.view.map(_.toByte).toArray
```

---

Original answer

I'm not intimately familiar with Scala-js, but I can elaborate on some of the questions that came up in the comments, and improve upon your self-answer.

> Also I don't quite get why I need toByte calls

```scala
class Uint8Array extends Object with TypedArray[Short, Uint8Array]
```

Scala treats a Uint8Array as a collection of `Short`, whereas you are expecting it to be a collection of `Byte`

Uint8Array's `toArray` method notes:

> This member is added by an implicit conversion from `Uint8Array` to
> `IterableOps[Short]` performed by method `iterableOps` in `scala.scalajs.js.LowestPrioAnyImplicits`.

So the method is returning an `Array[Short]` which you then `.map` to convert the `Short`s to `Byte`s.

In your answer you posted

```scala
 input.toArray.map(_.toByte)
```

which is technically correct, but it has the downside of allocating an intermediate array of the Shorts. To avoid this allocation, you can perform the `.map` operation on a `.view` of the array, then call `.toArray` on the view.

[Views](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/views.html) in Scala (and by extension Scala.js) are lightweight objects that reference an original collection plus some kind of transformation/filtering function, which can be iterated like any other collection. You can compose many transformation/filters on a view without having to allocate intermediate collections to represent the results. See the docs page (linked) for more.

```scala
input.view.map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Depending on how you intend to pass the resulting value around, you may not even need to call `.toArray`. For example if all you need to do is iterate the elements later on, you could just pass the view around as an `Iterable[Byte]` without ever having to allocate a separate array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'd put the actual code answer at the top for an easier find

Comment: I've performed some unscientific tests and found that using view is ~1.8 times slower than not using it (at least on Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.scalajs.js

def toScalaArray(input: js.typedarray.Uint8Array): Array[Byte] =
  input.toArray.map(_.toByte)
```

Comment: This was just a guess, I didn't actually attempt to test it. Does everything actually work out with signs etc.? Short can represent +255, signed byte cannot (aren't the sign issues the reason why they made it an `Iterable[Short]` in the first place?)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I only tested two-way conversion with -127 number and it worked fine

Comment: Uint8Array possible values are within 0 and 255. numbers 128-255 get converted to negative Byte numbers with no data loss (e.g. 255 maps to -1)